# Find a particular file name existence and execute batch command

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am looking for a PS script which will search for a particular file name and check its existence. If file exists it should execute a batch command.

```bsh
$version = "1.1.0"
$packageName = "example.DTO.$version"
Get-ChildItem "d:\Test" | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "$packageName.nupkg" }
```

and my batch command

```batch
C:\NugetRestore\nuget.exe push "d:\Test\$packageName.nupkg" saranuget -Source "http://123.456.78.90/myget" -Timeout 120
```

I am unable to integrate both this.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

This covers where the test matches multiple files:

```
$version = "1.1.0"
$packageName = "example.DTO.$version"
$FileCheck = Get-ChildItem "d:\Test" | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "$packageName.nupkg" }

$FileCheck | ForEach-Object {
    C:\NugetRestore\nuget.exe push "$($_.Fullname)" saranuget -Source "http://123.456.78.90/myget" -Timeout 120
}
```